# How to start timer accoirding to server response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to start countdown timer according to the server response. I first I made a timer for a local test in which I was passing Employee name, Hour, Min, and Sec. And it was working fine. But now I want to start countdown timer as server data. It will fetch Employee name and Countdown timer time in a minute.
But it is not splitting json object properly. It is showing var have undefined data.

> API Response- `[{"EmployeeName":"Abc","Hour":9,"Min":25},{"EmployeeName":"Xyz","Hour":11,"Min":41}]`

**Javascript**

```
function GetMachine() {

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'php/StitchTimer.php';
http.open('GET', url, true);

http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    var data = http.responseText;
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
     for(var i=0;i<jsonResponse.length;i++){
    var index = jsonResponse[i];
    console.log(index);
    var empname = index["EmployeeName"];
    var hour = index["Hour"];
    var minute = index["Min"];


    addEmployee(empname,hour,minute);
    }
}
http.send();
}
}
function addEmployee(emp,hr,mi)
        { 
            var employee = new Employee(emp,hr,mi,00);
            employeeList.appendChild(employee.domObj);
            employee.startTimer();
        }
    class Employee
        {   
            constructor(name,hr,min,sec)
            {
                var self=this;

                this.timer;
                this.timeInSec;
                this.domObj=document.createElement("div");
                this.timeSpan=document.createElement("span");

                this.domObj.style.backgroundColor = '#4CA';
                this.domObj.style.border = 'none';
                this.domObj.style.height = '100px';
                this.domObj.style.width = '100px';
                this.domObj.style.color = 'white';
                this.domObj.style.padding = '20px';
                this.domObj.style.textAlign = 'center';
                this.domObj.style.textDecoration = 'none';
                this.domObj.style.display = 'inline-block';
                this.domObj.style.fontSize = '26px';
                this.domObj.style.borderRadius = '50%';
                this.domObj.style.margin = '20px';
                this.domObj.style.justifyContent = "center";

                this.timeInSec=hr*60*60+min*60+parseInt(sec);
                this.timeSpan.innerHTML=hr+":"+min+":"+sec;
                this.domObj.innerHTML=name+"<br>";
                this.domObj.appendChild(this.timeSpan);
                console.log("0:"+this.timeInSec);
            }               
            startTimer()
            {
                this.timer=setInterval(this.updateTime.bind(this),1000);
            }
            updateTime()
            {
                var hr,min,sec,temp;

                if (this.timeInSec<=0)
                {
                    clearInterval(this.timer);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.timeInSec--;
                    //console.log("1:"+this.timeInSec);
                    sec=this.timeInSec % 60;
                    temp=this.timeInSec-sec;
                    temp/=60;
                    //console.log("2:"+temp);
                    min=temp % 60;
                    temp-=min;
                    hr=temp/60;

                    this.timeSpan.innerHTML=hr+":"+min+":"+sec;
                }
            }
}
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","pw","db");
    $currenttime = date("Y-m-d H:i");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Stitch` WHERE `EndTime` > '$currenttime' ";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $result = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $end = $row['EndTime'];
        $end = strtotime($end);
        $current = strtotime($currenttime);
        $timer = $end-$current;
        $timer = $timer/60;

        $hour = floor($timer/60);
        $min = $timer-($hour*60);

        $result[]=array('EmployeeName' =>$row['WorkerName'],'Hour'=>$hour,'Min'=>$min);
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: _"Problem is in constructor i have to pass Employenname, hour,min,sec all things"_ - So change the constructor requirements to match your needs?

Comment: In JS you can pass `undefined` to function params if you don't want to pass some values. So if you are not passing name, hr, sec do some thing like this, `new Employee('', 0, minute.value, 0);` - I didn't check your code in more detail. I'm not sure how good it is to avoid name for the employee. Other validation stuffs you have to handle.

Comment: Now i change my php code now i am passing Employee name, Hour and Min in json array. Now i want to capture it and store it in js variable.

Comment: Check my question now @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Check the for loop where you calll addEmployee(). It is inifinit loop.

Comment: Yes i changed. Check now. But i cannot store json object in var. Please check. @JiriSemmler

Comment: Ok I edited code again and it works well now. Problem is solved.

Comment: Just for future reference, don't update the code in the question to the "correct" code. That removes all history and won't be to any help for future visitors. You should keep the non-working code in the question and write an answer with the correct code (with an explanation what you did to fix it). That way, other people having the same issue will see the "before" and "after".

Comment: Yeah i will keep it in mind next time. Thanks. @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your original issue was but you could simplify the solution in several ways.

**1: Use the Fetch API**

The [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is available in all modern browsers and there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) for the IE10 browser. It provides a much cleaner interface for fetching resources in the browser - there's no need to mess about with readyState and response codes.

```
fetch(url)
.then(function(response){
  // return the response as JSON
  return response.json();
})
.then(function(data){
  // use the JSON data here
})
.catch(function(err){
  console.log('Request failed', err);
});
```

`fetch()` takes the data URL as a parameter and returns a **Promise**. If the `fetch()` action completes successfully the response will be passed to the `then()` chain, otherwise we will have an error to handle.

**2: Take advantage of JSON**

The data returned from the server is parsed to JSON. There's no need to copy individual elements to construct new objects because you already have an array of such objects.

Assuming the response from the server is:

```
[{"EmployeeName":"Abc","Hour":9,"Min":25},{"EmployeeName":"Xyz","Hour":11,"Min":41}]
```

Then `data` will be an array object containing that exact structure and you can iterate over the elements of the array using the `forEach()` method.

```
data.forEach(function(item){
  // item is the current element being processed
  console.log(item.EmployeeName);
  // Output:
  // "Abc"
  // "Xyz"
});
```

The `data` object contains the initial state and there is nothing stopping you from altering it to meet your needs. Remember that if you attempt to access a value or an attribute that doesn't exist it will be assigned a value with a type of `undefined`.

**3: Timers come with a cost**

Your solution declares a timer for each individual element returned in the array. If you need to display 1000 items then that's 1000 timers being declared. Alternatively you could implement a single timer and have the handler iterate through your collection of elements, updating the clock for each.

**4: The browser can style the content**

This is just a niggle. Instead of setting the same style attributes for each dynamically created element, define a CSS rule or add a style tag and add the appropriate CSS class to your new HTML elements. See [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) for more detailed examples.

```
var divElement = document.createElement('div');
divElement.classList.add('div-class-name');
```

Here is an implementation without the need for the `Employee` class and uses a single timer as described above. The state of the individual clocks is tracked using data attributes on the DOM elements but it could just as easily have been recorded in the original `data` object.

To try out the code, set the `dataUrl` variable to the correct URL for your data source.

**JavaScript:**

```
(function(){
  var dataUrl = ''; // where the data comes from
  var containerId = 'timers-container'; // existing container element in the DOM
  var activeClocksSelector = '#timers-container .timer-str.active';
  var dataAttrSeconds = 'data-seconds';
  var countdownTimerId;

  // helper to zero pad time elements
  function getZeroPaddedValue(value) {
    return (value < 10) ? '0' + value : value; 
  }

  // returns a correctly formatted time string
  function getFormattedTimeString(secondsParam) {
    var secondsNum = parseInt(secondsParam, 10);
    var hours = Math.floor(secondsNum / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((secondsNum - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = secondsNum - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);
    return getZeroPaddedValue(hours) + ':' + getZeroPaddedValue(minutes) + 
            ':' + getZeroPaddedValue(seconds);
  }

  // convert time elements to a number of seconds
  function getCountdownSeconds(hours, minutes, seconds) {
    var hh = (typeof hours !== 'undefined') ? parseInt(hours, 10) * 3600 : 0;
    var mm = (typeof minutes !== 'undefined') ? parseInt(minutes, 10) * 60 : 0;
    var ss = (typeof seconds !== 'undefined') ? parseInt(seconds, 10) : 0;
    return hh + mm + ss;
  }

  // setInterval callback handler
  function updateCountdownClocks() {
    var element, i, seconds;
    // get the active countdown clock elements
    var activeClockElements = document.querySelectorAll(activeClocksSelector);
    var numActiveClocks = activeClockElements.length;
    if (numActiveClocks > 0) {
      // loop through the elements
      for (i=0; i < numActiveClocks; i++) {
        element = activeClockElements[i];
        seconds = 0; // use a sensible default
        // check that the 'data-seconds' attribute is present
        if (element.hasAttribute(dataAttrSeconds)) {
          // decrement the number of seconds
          seconds = parseInt(element.getAttribute(dataAttrSeconds), 10) - 1;
        }
        // update the 'data-seconds' attribute
        element.setAttribute(dataAttrSeconds, seconds);
        // update the UI
        element.textContent = getFormattedTimeString(seconds);
        // check if counter needs to remain active
        if (seconds < 1) {
          element.classList.remove('active');
        }
      }
    } else {
      // remove the timer because the active clocks collection is empty
      clearInterval(countdownTimerId);
    }
  }

  // creates the DOM structure
  function setApplicationState(data) {
    // Are there items in the array?
    if (0 < data.length) {
      // get a handle on the DOM container element
      var container = document.getElementById(containerId);

      // use DocumentFragment object for efficiency
      var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

        // iterate through the array of data items
        data.forEach(function(item){
        // determine the number of seconds in the countdown timer
        var seconds = getCountdownSeconds(item.Hour, item.Min);
        // create HTML elements
        var outerDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');

        // populate outer div content
        outerDiv.classList.add('timer-block');
        outerDiv.textContent = item.EmployeeName;

        // populate inner div content
        innerDiv.classList.add('timer-str');
        // add a class to indicate the item is active
        if (0 < seconds) {
          innerDiv.classList.add('active');
        }
        // initialise the 'data-seconds' attribute
        innerDiv.setAttribute(dataAttrSeconds, seconds);
        innerDiv.textContent = getFormattedTimeString(seconds);
        // append the HTML elements
        outerDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
        fragment.appendChild(outerDiv);
      });

      // add the DocumentFragment to the DOM
      container.appendChild(fragment);
    }
    // must return a value
    return data;
  }

  // start the countdown clocks
  function startTheTimer(data) {
    // keep track of the interval ID
    countdownTimerId = setInterval(updateCountdownClocks, 1000);
    // promise chain must return a value
    return data;
  }

  // using the Fetch API to retrieve the initial state
  var state = fetch(dataUrl)
    .then(function(response){
      // return the parsed JSON content
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(setApplicationState)
    .then(startTheTimer)
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log('Request failed', err);
    });
})();
```

**CSS:**

```
#timers-container .timer-block {
  background-color: #4CA;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 26px;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="timers-container"></div>
```